# KSQL in AWS MSK

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, aws-msk

Does anyone have any idea if AWS MSK (Managed Streaming for Kafka) supports KSQL? I have seen many videos and documentations for KSQL on confluent platform but not for AWS MSK.

Please let me know if it supports and also let me know if there is any documentation on KSQL setup in AWS MSK.

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: Is there any alternative for KSQl to use with MSK? ( other than Kafka streams)

Answer (score 5):

KSQL can be installed on any Kafka cluster, hosted or otherwise. The documentation will be the exact same - configure the bootstrap servers and any relevant client properties

MSK doesn't offer KSQL because it's against the [Confluent Licensing](https://www.confluent.io/blog/license-changes-confluent-platform/)